# How to read entire content of a text file in batch

Tags: batch-file

I want to read entire content of a text file in a batch file.
I found this :

> for /f "delims=" %%x in (file.txt) do set content=%%x

but the "content" variable just has the last line, I want to read entire file into a single variable.

Comment: This can only work if the file is smaller than 8191 bytes, as variables are limited to this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your comment

> Is there any way to include lines in !content!

I assume you want linefeeds in your content variable, this can be done with an extra variable.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set LF=^


rem ** The two empty lines are necessary
set "content="

for /f "delims=" %%x in (file.txt) do (
  set "content=!content!%%x!LF!"
)
echo(!content!

endlocal
```

Comment: This prints nothing for me.  I set the correct file, and gave the file contents.  The echo command prints nothing.

Comment: @TrevorHickey You should open a new question and link to this one. Did you test it already with `ECHO ON`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure the exact format you are looking for in the 'content' variable, but this code should do the trick (The code simply sets content to blank, then loops through each line of file.txt and copies the line into content using delayed expansions):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set content=

for /f "delims=" %%x in (file.txt) do (set content=!content! %%x)
echo !content!

endlocal
```

Comment: But you should echo `!content!` not `%var%`

Comment: But you should also use `echo(!content!` instead of `echo %content%`, else there could be problems with special characters, keywords like `ON` or `/?` or ...

Comment: @jeb I agree, but just to clarify...the `echo %content%` line was purely there for demonstrative purposes that the code will set all of the file.txt file into the `content` variable.

Comment: @Jeff It's ok but all text is a single line in !content! Is there any way to include lines in !content!?

Answer (score -2):

On a modern copy of windows you may also do:

```
powershell -Command cat "<file name>"
```

The only HEADS UP is that:

```
powershell YourScriptFile.ps1
```

will NOT execute by default unless you modify system security settings... as I learned when I tried to build a 'cat' command. That said, for one or two liners like this, why beat your head against the wall when you may take advantage of this on most modern systems.