# batch file, read json file into string

Tags: batch-file

I need to read a json file:

```
{
   "key": {
       "subkey": "value"
   }
}
```

so I can pass it as an argument to a command:

```
program -e SETTINGS=<JSON FILE AS STRING>
```

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12977190/6738015) is what you want!

Comment: Before trying to automate this I'd check if it works with a condensed string like this with escaped inner double quotes `program -e "SETTINGS={\"key\":{\"subkey\": \"value\"}}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combining the answers to these questions...

- [How to read entire content of a text file in batch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12977190/7571258)
- [Escape “double quotes” inside batch's input parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11893337/7571258)

... we can write the following batch file:

```
:: Make it possible to read immediate value of variable using !variable! syntax.
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Read file "test.json" into variable data, removing line breaks.
set data=
for /f "delims=" %%x in (test.json) do set "data=!data!%%x"

:: Escape double quotes in data
set data=%data:"=\"%

:: Finally call program with the entire content of the JSON file as parameter
program -e "SETTINGS=%data%"
```

Note that when using the `cmd.exe` command processor, the [maximum length for a commandline and also for environment variables is **8191** characters](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830473/command-prompt-cmd--exe-command-line-string-limitation), so this will obviously restrict the maximum size of the JSON file you can pass.

Comment: Your length limit is misleading / not relevant - batch is further restricted to 8191 max length for variables and also for command lines.